# potential Wireless Adapter issue with wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, network-adapter

So I have a computer which is connecting to my router using a wireless USB adapter. I also have a mobile device which i am testing with. I noticed extreme Wifi issues in which i would lag extremely bad in games i play.

After doing a speed test turns out i am getting 20mb download. When i do a speed test on the phone the same time, i get a stable 70mb+ download rate. Is there something wrong with my adapter? I have tried to update the driver using the option of "searching online auto for driver" but it says i have latest one. Additionaly, i sometimes expereince just my wifi on computer stop working and adapter cuts out. After unplugging and plugging the adapter back in, connectivity is back with no problem.

My adapter spec: IEEE 802.11 b/g/n 2.4 GHZ (N300 Netgear adapter)

How can i troubleshoot this further and decide what the issue is. Am i right in thinking i need a new adapter?

Comment: did you install the latest driver for the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

- Install the latest driver for the USB wifi card
- Update your access point's firmware
- Go into the adapter's configuration and ensure that N mode is turned on; 20-22Mbps is right on the max actual throughput for 802.11g, "54Mbps"
- Check the actual negotiated rate; if it's above 54Mbps (and stays above even when doing the speed test), something else is happening
- Make sure your access point is in WPA2-AES mode (TKIP may be extremely slow on some devices)
- Try the [speedof.me](https://speedof.me/) test on both devices
- Move that USB wifi card to another machine and see if anything changes.
- Buy another adapter with external antennas for a test, perhaps like an [Alfa AC1200](http://www.alfa.com.tw/products_show.php?pc=137&ps=225)

  - Or borrow whatever you can for testing on that computer